# Problem with a Functor instance over the keys in Map from Data.Map

Tags: haskell, dictionary, instance, typeclass, functor

I'm trying to write [Eric Kidd's](http://www.randomhacks.net/articles/2007/02/21/refactoring-probability-distributions) and [Sigfpe's](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2007/03/independence-entanglement-and.html) code for a probability monad using Data.Map as a backend but I'm stuck with a Functor instance.

I have a data type which is a probability table:

```
newtype Prob f a = Prob {table :: Map a f}
```

which at each value for the variable of type `a` associate is probability, which is of type `Floating f => f`. The instance should be given by:

```
instance (Floating f) => Functor (Prob f) where 
   fmap f (Prob tab) = Prob (mapKeysWith (+) f tab)
```

but `mapKeysWith` have type `(Ord k2) => Map k1 a -> (a -> a -> a) -> (k1 -> k2) -> Map k2 a`. I have no way of enforcing the `Ord` constraint in the instance, and so I have a type error.

Is there a simple way out of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing simple, I'm afraid; it's a well known problem with `Functor` (and `Monad`).  As usual, [Oleg](http://haskell.spreadshirt.com/oleg-already-did-it-A6499531) has a [solution](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2010-July/080978.html) (for `Set`, but `Map` is solved the same way) if you can rewrite to use a replacement `Functor` instance.  (See also [`liboleg`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/liboleg) on [Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/hackage/).)